# Update of a method in Keras and import

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I've updated the method Dropout in Keras to, let's say, Dropout2. Then I am trying to import the new Keras module in google colaboratory. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, just solved it with [pip install documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git)